# Where is the Display Calibrator Assistant on my hard drive?

Tags: macos, system-settings, preferences, color

I'd like to use the **Display Calibrator Assistant** without going through the process of opening the system preferences.

**Does anyone know where the program is located on my hard drive?**

I've done a search for various keywords without being able to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app can be found at this path:

```
/System/Library/ColorSync/Calibrators/Display Calibrator.app
```

To run directly from Terminal type:

```
open -a /System/Library/ColorSync/Calibrators/Display\ Calibrator.app
```

This will pop-up a small window on every monitor you have connected.